# How to keep boxes on the same line or centered under each other?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a section that contains 6 articles. I have sized these article boxes to fit the screen of an iPhone. If the computer screen is large enough I want them to line up side by side like this;

```
######
```

But as the screen gets smaller I want them to drop to the line bellow but be centered in the page like these:

```
#####
  #
```

---

```
####
 ##
```

---

```
###
###
```

---

```
##
##
##
```

---

```
#
#
#
#
#
#
```

I would prefer an only CSS method to do this, but if there isn't one I will try others. I have searched this site the web and several books and I have not been able to find a way to do this.

Comment: you need some sort of css grid layout system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `text-align:center` to the container, and `display:inline-block` to the item.

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9jfkrzkv/)**

```css
.wrap {
    text-align: center;
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```

Further reading - [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: This worked though I did have to remove the spacing between the article elements so there borders would collapse. Other than that it works like a charm thanks.

Comment: @sjtwiv The white spacing thing is very common with inline elements, you can follow the link above to read more, my favorite solution is using `font-size` tricks. Other than that, `box-sizing:border-box` can be very useful too.

Answer (score -2):

You should look into using a framework, if anything to make everything cross-browser happy. Most frameworks have such a responsive design layout system to do exactly what you need.

My favorite is the Twitter Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/

w3schools also has a lightweight framework you might like if you want more control: http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp

good luck